# Recovering URL don't return expected result

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on .Net App in C# and I have problem,after I got latest version from Source Control my application can't start. After Debugging I found that these lines:

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
var requestedResourceAbsoluteUrl = app.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower();
```

return not the Default.aspx page, but only  Default(with missing .aspx in the end). I tried everything. Mapped again the solution. Tried in different browsers, repaired Visual Studio. I used Fiddler to detect the request. This is about every page in the application. Everything is OK with my coworkers project wich checkined this version

Comment: Why do you use `HttpApplication` ? Why not just use `Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower()` ?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Usually error like this are due to http header defaults being wrong.  The defaults are using the IE browser settings and the settings may be different on your PC than coworkers PC.  I would compare sniffer results on your PC with coworkers.

Comment: Hello, I tried everything but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution: I deleted all history, cookies, cache and other data in the browsers and now everything seems fine. It keeps not working in IE.